# Automatically Diagram Pointer Structure with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Suppose one has a program with many data objects that have pointers to other objects. How could one use TikZ to automatically draw a diagram of the pointer structure?

I'm thinking of outputting the addresses of all the data objects and of the pointers, but I'm not sure how I'd need to parse these data into a format TikZ could then use to draw the graph/network.

For example, for a certain list of the addresses of structs and pointers, TikZ could produce a graph like this:

[image]

Comment: I think [`forest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) can help you. It can draw `trees` programmaticly.

Comment: @Ignasi: Perhaps you could convert this comment into an answer, and maybe even give a short example? I've never heard of `forest` before. Are there any other packages that "can draw `trees` programmaticly"?

Comment: @Geremia If you look at the tag for `forest` you will find *lots* of examples. The same if you click on the `tikz-trees` tag or look up the `trees` tag. It isn't clear what good an example here would so since we have no idea what you've tried or how you are getting the data into your document. I don't understand what that diagram is supposed to show, to be honest. You might be better off looking at TikZ's graph drawing facilities (see the manual) since what you've shown is not, in fact, a tree at all.